# How to compare string struct array in File for C program

Tags: c

I'm coding a project for account transaction. However, there are some little problems in my checking account ID process. I used struct function belong string array, which can help me easily to solve my subtasks later, the point is as I try to check the account_ID by using string compare. The output cannot display my expectation. I don't know how to scan a variable in array to check with the string-array struct in File-text.

I endeavoured to scan a variable by so much ways. But it doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
struct customers{
char phone[13];
char id[9];
char name[31];
char address[201];
char city[31];
char date[11];}customer

int main()
{
   FIle *fc
   if((fc=fopen("clients.txt","a+"))=NULL)
        printf("Can not open");
   else
   {
        int i = 0, a = 0;
        fflush(stdin);
        customer_ID:
          printf("Enter the ID (maximum 8 digits): ";
          gets(customer[i].id);
        if (strlen(customer[i].id)!=8)
        {
            printf("Wrong the number of digits ! Enter Again!\n");
            goto customer_ID;
        } 
          while(fscanf(fc,"%s\n%[^\n]%*c%s\n%[^\n]%*c%[^\n]%*c%s\n\n",customer[a].id,customer[a].name,customer[a].phone,customer[a].address,customer[a].city,customer[a].date)!=EOF)
    {
        if (strcmp(customer[i].id,customer[a].id)==0)
        {
            printf("Account ID has been already used ! Please Enter other ID !\n");
            goto customer_ID;
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT: 
       * Actual Result:
              It don't print "Account ID has been already used ! Please Enter other ID !"

```
   * Expected Result:
          Print "Account ID has been already used ! Please Enter other ID !"
```

Comment: Who or what text suggested using `fflush(stdin);`?

Comment: Code does not compile, consider re-posting with true compilable code.

Comment: `i` and `a` are both 0.  What do you expect is the result of comparing the same string?

Comment: Side-note: `(fc=fopen("clients.txt","a+"))=NULL` will always be false, and also has a side-effect of setting `fc` to NULL

Comment: Also note that `fscanf` might fail and return values other than `EOF`.  You are best to compare the return value against the expected number of items to read.  Or better still, don't use `fscanf` since it can easily overflow your buffers.

Comment: Thank for your advices

Comment: There's absolutely no need for a `goto` in this code.  Why not use `while (1)`, then `break` when the input is valid and/or `continue` when it is not?  That's how most people would do it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try use strstr in case that the id is always in the same size so that it will be

```
if (strstr(customer[i].id,customer[a].id))
```

and that way your Durable code spaces